# How to solve highly oscillating differential equation

Tags: computational-physics, differential-equations, numerical-method, anharmonic-oscillators

The equation looks like: $$x''(t)+bx'(t)+c x(t)+dx^3(t)=0.$$ This is the motion of a particle in a potential $cx^2/2+dx^4/4$ with friction force $bx'$. In my case, the friction term is very small and the particle will oscillate **billions** of times before the magnitude decreases significantly. So how do we solve this kind of equations to a very late final moment when the magnitude almost dies out?

Mathematica or Matlab doesn't work because of the stiffness problem, i.e. the particle oscillates so fast that we need to set the step size extremely small in order to have reliable numerical result. Another difficulty is the potential energy is not symmetric around the minimum ($c<0$,$d>0$). Thus I guess we cannot use the approximate form for the solution : $y(x)=A(t)\cos(ω(t)t)$.

Thanks a lot for any kind of suggestions!

Comment: Can't you just scale time? Basically let $$t' = \beta t$$ and $\beta$ is just a large constant.

Comment: @docscience I am comparing two time scales. The first one is period of oscillation $T$, the second one is the scale that magnitude decreases significantly (say it takes $\tau$ to decrease by half). I need to solve the equation from $0 \to 10 \tau$. Scaling time will change both of them so it does not really help.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solving an ODE numerically. Perhaps [math.se] or [scicomp.se] might be better suited for this question.

Comment: This question is from electroweak symmetry breaking. Sorry I should have posted it in other sections.

Comment: If you have to resolve the high frequency oscillations, you have no choice that I'm aware of. If, however, you only care about some time scale between the smallest and steady state, you can use an implicit scheme to avoid the stiffness problem and pick a time step that gives you adequate resolution of the highest-frequency mode you are interested in solving.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the friction term as a perturbation. During all the stages of the motion, the effect of the friction is always small on small time scales. So, it always looks like as if the motion exactly fits the solution of the differential equation where b is set to zero. However, over long periods of time the value of the integration constants will slowly drift. This means that you can use the variation of constants method.

So, you formally solve the differential equation for the quartic potential (of course, you can't solve this exactly, but it's rather trivial to let a computer generate accurate numerical solutions given the initial conditions). The solution depends on two integration constants (e.g. the initial position and velocity), let's call these parameters A and B. Then you treat A and B as dynamical variables, the solution for the frictionless case merely defines the transform from x and dx/dt to A and B.

You then consider the coupled differential equations for A and B. In A -B space the system is almost stationary, allowing you to take large time steps in the numerical algorithm to approximate the solution.

Comment: @lblis I don't get how to go from initial conditions to A and B? If we solve the equation numerically, aren't the information of A and B lost?

Comment: It may be easier to just solve the quartic oscillator exactly in terms of elliptic functions, you then get expressions completely analogous to the harmonic oscillator, instead of trigonometric functions you get  elliptic functions. Then it's analogous to what would happen if d were zero and you had the amplitude and the phase as your A and B.